# how to make urllib POST with auth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I trying to make a POST call using [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) (python 3.5), but can't figure it out. There are plenty examples on how to make either [POST call without auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491541/python3-json-post-request-without-requests-library) or [call with auth, but GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708708/http-basic-authentication-not-working-in-python-3-4)... I'm struggling to put 2 and 2 together! Could someone please help me with a code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238925/python-urllib-urllib2-post

Comment: `auth` in `requests` is much easier. you can use that - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/. Also can you actually post your code so we have any idea what you tried?

Comment: Thanks for responses, but I have to use urllib, not requests.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I could not any reference to auth, as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
import urllib.request  

auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='name',
                          uri='url',
                          user='user',
                          passwd='pass')
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
req = urllib.request.Request(url=some_url, data=data, method='POST')
urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```